# angularjs shrink down picture from mobile phone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, mobile, firebase

I'm developing a very simple angular app for a tournament were we want to administrate some statistics for the contestants. So far to so good and have it develop with angular and firebase.

Now I want to use picture for the contestants scale it down before converting to Base64 and finally upload it to firebase. I'm using on site my smartphone to take picture from the contestants.

**My question is** how to scala the down the picture taken by the smartphone down to as small as it possible to see the face and minimise the usage of 3g/4g for my and the user on site.

do you have some experience with that kind of situation? And is this a ok for Firebase to taka long string (I'm quite new to Firebase services)?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the uploaded image onto a `canvas` element, resize the canvas, and then dump that to a base64 data URL, you should be able to post that to your backend without much trouble.

To take an file inputs contents and put them onto a canvas you would:

```
var tempImage  = new Image();
var fileReader = new FileReader();
var canvas     = angular.element('canvas').eq(0);

// Step: 3: Once the image is loaded, set up the contents on a canvas, resize, and export to data url for storage.
tempImage.onload = function() {
  canvas.width  = tempImage.width;
  canvas.height = tempImage.height;

  var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvasContext.drawImage(tempImage, 0, 0, 400, 400);

  // Send this to firebase
  console.log(canvasContext.toDataURL('image/png'));
};

// Step 2: Once the file is selected, we'll load the result into a temporary image.
fileReader.onload = function() {
  tempImage.src = fileReader.result;
};

// Step 1: Wait for file to be selected via the input.
angular.element('input[type="file"]').on('change', function() {
  var image = angular.element(this).eq(0).input.files[0];
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(image);
});
```

This doesn't handle resizing to different aspect ratios, but you can figure out the math on that one. If you require a more complex cropping interface you might as well bring in the help of a library such as http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper which could get the same job done in a more elegant fashion.

On the mobile side of things you'll probably want the file input to support the camera so you could do the following when writing the markup:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

And you don't have to have the temporary canvas or images appear anywhere for this all to work, they're simply present to grab dimensions and do the manipulations on the image.